# Xcode copying unnecessary files into target

Tags: ios, xcode

In my Xcode project, I have it set to copy all the files I need in the "Copy bundle resources" step and it doesn't link to any extra libraries, yet when I compile the project it copies a number of files that aren't even in the project's file references (a number of .dll files that have nothing to do with this version of the app).

The files may have accidentally been added to the "copy bundle resources" step at one point but were since removed. How can I find out why are these files still being copied and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the files were left over from a build before those files were removed. Trashing the app from the products folder got rid of the extra files.